# Linebreak in \thanks footnote?

Tags: line-breaking, footnotes, titles

I am using the `scrartcl` class of `Koma-Script` with `\thanks` on the title page. Everything works as expected, so far, but I'd like to use a linebreak within the footnote.

Here's an MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper, DIV=11, titlepage]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{bigfoot}

\begin{document}

    \title{Spotting Miscellaneous Anomalies}
    \subtitle{A Field Guide for the Utterly Confused}
    \author{Nomen~\textsc{Nescio\,}\thanks{University of Nonesuchplace, Departement of Odds and Ends}} 
    \maketitle

\end{document}
```

I'd like to be "Departement" (after Nonesuchplace) to be on a new line, but `\\` just produces 101 (or so) errors. Any ideas?

Comment: I removed the [tag:koma-script] tag because the problem also shows up for standard classes.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

As a workaround use `\newline` instead of `\\`.

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper, DIV=11, 

titlepage]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{bigfoot}

\begin{document}

    \title{Spotting Miscellaneous Anomalies}
    \subtitle{A Field Guide for the Utterly Confused}
    \author{Nomen~\textsc{Nescio\,}\thanks{University of Nonesuchplace,\newline Departement of Odds and Ends}} 
    \maketitle

\end{document}
```

Comment: The spacing seems a little bit of with this solution, is that intentional?

Comment: It's the same spacing you'd get by default with "normal" footnotes. It should be possible to change this (but that's rather a follow-up question).

Comment: Or ``\protect\\``

Comment: `\newline` works fine for me, so thanks for that. I always thought \\ was just a shortcut, but ... live & learn :)